# Problem with understanding functions calling functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am new to python and have a problem with understanding functions and calling one function within the other. I made some improvised code to show you my problem, I just keep on getting an error saying that variable "comp" from  the function is not defined when I call it within the other function.. just don't understand. Help please, I am getting frustrated with this :)

```
import random

def start_game():
    start=input("Would you like to start the game? y/n ").lower()


def c_turn():
    print("Computer's turn: ")
    comp=print(random.choice(["rock","paper", "scissors"]))
    return  comp

def p_turn():
    player=input ("Now it's your turn: ")
    return player

def compare():
    c_turn()
    p_turn()
    if comp=="rock" and player=="scissors":
        print("Computer wins")
    elif comp=="rock" and player=="paper":
        print("Player wins")
    elif comp=="scissors" and player=="rock":
        print("Player wins")
    elif comp=="scissors" and player=="paper":
        print("Computer wins")
    elif comp=="paper" and player=="scissors":
        print("Player wins")
    elif comp=="paper" and player=="rock":
        print("Computer wins")
    elif comp==player:
        print("IT'S A TIE!")

start_game()
compare()
```

Comment: You either need to declare `comp` as a global variable, or pass it as a parameter to your functions on every function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the returned values from `c_turn()` and `p_turn()` so you can use them in the `compare()` function, otherwise they are simply discarded. For example:

```
def compare():
    comp = c_turn()
    player = p_turn()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to Python I suggest you to take a look at the following URL to understand the scope of variables before doing stuff with python.

[Scope of variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespaces-and-scope-in-python/) 
[Functions in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

As for the solution, you can convert your variables to global (as mentioned in the comments)

You can actually find these kinds of solutions by simply googling.
Anyways try referring to the links.
I hope it helps!